# How can I work on both forms at the same time on ms access?

Tags: ms-access

I am using ms access from ms pro plus 2019.

I created a form with a subform inside for my repurchasing creation. This has Default View as "Single form"

Additionally, I created product creation form which has Default View as "split form." This is where I can create new product and see my product lists above at the same time.

However, I recently have transformed the form to "Continuous form" to display my product lists with bigger appearance but unable to be edited unless the user (I) has clicked on a button leading to the old form used to create new product and now has changed to "single form" default view.

Everything seemed fine until the time I tested the new update. I found out that I can still work on other forms when I open my repurchasing creation form. In contrary, I can't work on other object besides my newly created "product display page" although I am still able to edit my product list and create new product detail while I am working between the display form (continuous form) and product creation (single form). Other than these two forms I am not allowed even to use my cursor clicking another screen/that of the repurchasing creation form/other access forms. The Three things I could do here is to quit the application, to close both forms before getting back to the repurchasing creation form, or to switch to other application.

My question is how can I work on both forms at the same time on ms access? I would like to use both forms simultaneously since there is time I could not remember all the product lists I have just restocked and each suppliers do not share the same product code. On  the other hand, using split form is not the way I found effective since I found myself a number of time mistaken prices among my products due to the size of the list displays using split forms.

Has anyone experience similar issue and if so could you please share your solution to this for me?

Thank you so much in advance for your time and generosity!

Comment: Appears to be a design issue, not coding, so not really appropriate for SO. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: Never used the split form, but I often used a similar design where the main form is _continuous_ and the sub form is _single_. The trick is to put the subform in the FOOTER of the main form. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

One way would be to set the two forms as popup. That would allow you to open both forms (even if one of the forms was a form + subform setup). And in fact, with the popup setting, you can even drag the forms right off and out of the main Access UI window.

Another way - especially with larger monitors?

Create a new big large form. And then while in design mode, drag the first form, and then the 2nd from from the nav pane into this larger form. This will thus allow and show the two forms as side by side inside of these new larger main form you create. This new main form will not really have any other purpose then to "hold" the two forms you want to display at the same time.

There is also STILL support in Access for what we call the older UI (windows "MIDI" or the so called multiple document interface). With the rise of tablets, phones, browsers all now using a "tab" like control across the top, then Access (and most of office) has also followed this design trend.

However, you CAN CHANGE the application to use the "older"  multiple document interface that we don't see used much anymore.

Go file->options->current database, and choose this option:

[image]

When you choose the above setting (you have to re-start access).

Then when you open one form? (even a form with sub form), then you can open other forms also. Each form opened now will have its own separate window - and thus you can open 5 forms at the same time and see them all - monitor size permitting.

So you have quite a few options here.

```
You can create that big main form - drop in the two forms as sub forms
You can open the forms as POP up. This allows even dragging forms outside, or to 2nd monitor
You can change the application wide settings to overlapping windows
```

And there is a probably a few more ways and options here - but the above ideas should keep you busy - try them out - see which one works best for you.